# Error 1193. Unable to connect to mysql. Cannot fetch data or insert data

Tags: php, mysql

Not uable to connect to mysql

When I am trying to run php files in browser it gives me error that con is not 
defined in db_functions.php file

And other thing is that Error : 1193 is coming That is variable 'a' not defined in db_connect.php file

Please help.
From last 1 week I am trying to connect but unable to connect

Though data is available when running viewusers.php it says no data available

Config.php file

```
 <?php
 /**
 * DB configuration variables
  */
           define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
           define("DB_USER", "root");
           define("DB_PASSWORD", "mayur123");
           define("DB_DATABASE", "db");
  ?>
```

db_connect.php

```
   <?php

    class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
     function __construct() {

     }

     // destructor
     function __destruct() {
    // $this->close();
    }

   // Connecting to database
   public function connect() {
    require_once 'config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);



   /* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
   }

if (!mysqli_query($con, "SET a=1")) {
  printf("Errorcode: %d\n", mysqli_errno($con));
  printf("Message : %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}



// return database handler

    return $con;
}

// Closing database connection
public function close() {
    mysqli_close();
}

} 
?>
```

db_function.php

```
   <?php
     /**
    * DB operations functions
    */
   class DB_Functions {

private $db;

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {
    include_once './db_connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($User) {


    // Insert user into database
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user(Name) VALUES('$User')");

   if ($result) {
       return true;
    } else {            
          // For other errors
            return false;
    }
}
 /**
 * Getting all users
 */
public function getAllUsers() {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * FROM user");
    return $result;
}
/**
 * Get Yet to Sync row Count
 */
public function getUnSyncRowCount() {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE syncsts = FALSE");
    return $result;
}
/**
 * Update Sync status of rows
 */
public function updateSyncSts($id, $sts){
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE user SET syncsts = $sts WHERE Id = $id");
    return $result;
   }
 }

     ?>
```

insertuser.php

```
            <?php 
            /**
             * Insert User into DB
             */ ?>
            <style>
            body {
              font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
            }
            div.header{
            padding: 10px;
            background: #e0ffc1;
            width:30%;
            color: #008000;
            margin:5px;
            }
            table {
              border-collapse: collapse;
              width: 25%;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
            }
            form{
            width: 30%;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 2px solid #edd3ff;
            }
            div#msg{
            margin-top:10px;
            width: 30%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: center;
            }
            </style>
            <center>
            <div class="header">
            Android SQLite and MySQL Sync - Add Users
            </div>
            </center>
            <form method="POST">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Name:</td><td><input name="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Add User"/></td></tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            <?php
            include_once './db_functions.php';
            //Create Object for DB_Functions clas
            if(isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"])){
            $db = new DB_Functions(); 
            //Store User into MySQL DB
            $uname = $_POST["username"];
            $res = $db->storeUser($uname);
                //Based on inserttion, create JSON response
                if($res){ ?>
                     <div id="msg">Insertion successful</div>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                     <div id="msg">Insertion failed</div>
                <?php }
            } else{ ?>
             <div id="msg">Please enter name and submit</div>
            <?php }
            ?>
```

view_users.php

```
                <?php
                /**
                 * Displays User information
                 */
                ?>
                <html>
                <head><title>View Users</title>
                <style>
                body {
                  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
                }
                table {
                  border-collapse: collapse;
                  width: 20%;
                  margin-left: auto;
                  margin-right: auto;
                }
                tr > td {
                  padding: 0.25rem;
                  text-align: center;
                  border: 1px solid #ccc;
                }
                tr:nth-child(even) {
                  background: #FAE1EE;
                }
                tr:nth-child(odd) {
                  background: #edd3ff;
                }
                tr#header{
                background: #c1e2ff;
                }
                td#sync{
                background: #fff;
                }
                div.header{
                padding: 10px;
                background: #e0ffc1;
                width:30%;
                color: #008000;
                margin:5px;
                }
                div.refresh{
                margin-top:10px;
                width: 5%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                }
                div#norecord{
                margin-top:10px;
                width: 15%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                }
                img{
                height: 32px;
                width: 32px;
                }
                </style>
                <script>
                var val= setInterval(function(){
                location.reload();
                },2000);
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                <center>
                <div class="header">
                Android SQLite and MySQL Sync - View Users
                </div>
                </center>
                <?php
                    include_once 'db_functions.php';
                    $db = new DB_Functions();
                    $users = $db->getAllUsers();
                    if ($users != false)
                        $no_of_users = mysqli_num_rows($users);
                    else
                        $no_of_users = 0;

                ?>
                <?php
                    if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                ?>
                <table>
                <tr id="header"><td>Id</td><td>Username</td><td>Sync Status</td></tr>
                <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {
                ?> 
                <tr>
                <td><span><?php echo $row["Id"] ?></span></td>
                <td><span><?php echo $row["Name"] ?></span></td>
                <td id="sync"><span>
                <?php 
                if($row["syncsts"])
                { 
                echo "<img src='img/green.png'/>"; 
                }else { 
                echo "<img src='img/white.png'/>";
                } 
                ?></span></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </table>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <div id="norecord">
                No records in MySQL DB
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Please whittle this down. There is a lot of irrelevant code here. Also, change your password immediately. Not only is it a weak password, but you just shared it with the entire world.

Comment: As a starting point, you refer to `$con` in a lot of methods where no such variable is defined. That's going to cause problems. You need to pass a valid connection, if you pass anything for that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con, "SET a=1")) {
  printf("Errorcode: %d\n", mysqli_errno($con));
  printf("Message : %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}
```

what is `"SET a=1"`  , maybe you should remove them.